# how to read json Dictionary

Tags: ios, json

i have to read json data and not getting .mp3 file i dont know how to get it please help me

my code is

```
 NSArray *ar = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[dict objectForKey:@"pronunciations"]];
 for (NSString *key in [dict objectForKey:@"pronunciations"])
 {
     for (NSDictionary *dictpro in ar)
     {
         NSLog(@"key2   is %@",key);
         NSLog(@"title for key2 is %@",[dict objectForKey:key] );
     }
 }
```

and response is 
key2   is

```
{
   audio =    
   (
       {
           type = pronunciation;
           url = "/v2/dictionaries/assets/ldoce/gb_pron/abate0205.mp3";
       }
   );

   ipa = "\U0259\U02c8be\U026at";
}

2013-11-30 10:53:37.756 TestJson[419:c07] title for key2 is (null)
```

i have to read .mp3 file please help me.

Comment: Please put whole JSON response...

Comment: JSON data? MP3? I don't see a question about either of those. Did you forget to ask your question?

Comment: key   is pronunciations
 title for key is (
        {
        audio =         (
                        {
                type = pronunciation;
                url = "/v2/dictionaries/assets/ldoce/gb_pron/abate0205.mp3";
            }
        );
        ipa = "\U0259\U02c8be\U026at";
    }
)
 
}

)                     i want to use .mp3 file.

Comment: Agree Gabe, There is no JSON dictionary as well as any MP3...

Comment: actually i am using json first time,so dont know how to read this type  json response.

Comment: You are using JSON. You will get response when you send a request for on a web method hosted by web service... Just show me that JSON web service or else the response of JSON which you have got..

Comment: Please show the json response

Comment: https://api.pearson.com/v2/dictionaries/entries/cqAEvSG2D0

Comment: i want to use audio file in this url.

Comment: Yes, 2 min.. I got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
//NSDictionary *dict1=[Jsondict objectForKey:@"pronunciations"];
NSArray *array1=[Jsondict objectForKey:@"audio"];
NSDictionary *dict2=[array1 objectatIndex:1];

NSLog(@"%@",[Jsondict objectForKey:@"url"]);
NSLog(@"%@",[Jsondict objectForKey:@"ipa"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it,
Do the following

```
NSDictionary *dictResult = [JSONRepsponse objectForKey:@"result"];
NSDictionary *dictPronunciations = [dictResult valueForKey:@"pronunciations"];
NSDictionary *dictAudio = [dictPronunciations valueForKey:@"audio"];
NSString *strMp3Path = [dictAudio valueForKey:@"url"];
NSString *commonUrl = @"https://api.pearson.com";
NSString *strUrl = [commonUrl stringByAppendingString:strMp3Path];
NSURL *url =  [NSURL URLWithString:[strUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSData *dataMp3 = [NSData dataWithURL : url];
```

You can use this data to play Mp3 in AvAudio Player

Answer (score -1):

Assume this is your JSON response(Key2):

```
{
   audio =    
   (
       {
           type = pronunciation;
           url = "/v2/dictionaries/assets/ldoce/gb_pron/abate0205.mp3";
       }
   );

   ipa = "\U0259\U02c8be\U026at";
}
```

and you need to get `"/v2/dictionaries/assets/ldoce/gb_pron/abate0205.mp3"`.
Then you can do this:

```
NSArray *audio = key2["audio"];

// If there have multiple dictionary in audio array
NSMutableArray *urls = [@[] mutableCopy];
for (NSDictionary *dic in audio) {
    [urls addObject:dic[@"url"]];
}

// Otherwise
NSString *url = audio[0][@"url"];
```

The overall should look like this:

```
NSArray *ar = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[dict objectForKey:@"pronunciations"]];
NSMutableArray *urlArray = [@[] mutableCopy];
for (NSString *key in ar) {
    NSArray *audio = key["audio"];
    // If there have multiple dictionary in audio array
    NSMutableArray *urls = [@[] mutableCopy];
    for (NSDictionary *dic in audio) {
        [urls addObject:dic[@"url"]];
    }
    [urlArray addObject:urls];

    // Otherwise
    NSString *url = audio[0][@"url"];
    [urlArray addObject:url];
}
```

Comment: It is a patch... You need to provide a sound and smart solution for any problem so that it can work in all the scenarios...

Comment: Thank you, I'll improve this answer.